# How to limit only images to be uploaded through file_field tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

```
<%= form_for @model_name, :url => {:controller => 'controller_name', :action => 'index'},:html => {:multipart => true},:validate => true do |f| %>

<%= file_field 'upload', 'datafile'%>

<% end %>
```

I have this form. I want to upload only images through this upload. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem to manage file attachments. It has `validates_attachment` validator which would be helpful.

```
validates_attachment :avatar, :presence => true,
  :content_type => { :content_type => "image/jpg" },
  :size => { :in => 0..10.kilobytes }
```

Comment: paperclip is deprecated. I voted-up solution from Chris Bailey

Answer (score 15):

HTML5

```
<%= f.file_field :file, multiple: true, accept:'image/*' %>
```

Comment: This disables selecting non-image files in the file browser, but it's still possible to drag and drop the file onto the file field button. (Tested on Chrome, Mac)

Comment: A solid solution must also include backend validation... Chris Bailey offers a complementary validation.

Answer (score 1):

You can still do a simple validation based on the content type:

```
class MyModels < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :upload_is_image

  ...

  private

  def upload_is_image
    unless upload and upload.content_type =~ /^image\/(jpeg|pjpeg|gif|png|bmp)$/
      errors.add(:upload, "Not a valid image")
    end
  end

end
```

obviously you can tweak the regexp depending on what sort of images you want to accept.